# How do I use a string to select an enum value in Javascript (with typescript)?

Tags: javascript, string, typescript, types, enums

I'm working with microbits in JS with static typescript, and I'm using this code:

```
freq = music.noteFrequency(Note.CSharp3)
music.playTone(freq, 1000)
```

where freq is an integer, music.noteFrequency is a predefined function and Note is a predefined enum with set note values. This should return the frequency of the note CSharp3. This works fine.

I want to be able to take a string `note = "CSharp3"` and use it to select a note, and get the frequency. I've tried

`freq = music.noteFrequency(Note.valueOf(note))`

`freq = music.noteFrequency(Note[note])`
among other things.

I'm getting the error:

Property 'valueOf' does not exist on type 'typeof Note'.

or

Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.

respectively.

What am I doing wrong?

It's some kind of typescript based issue, but I don't know what.

Comment: `Note[note]` should work totally fine. That error message doesn't sound like JS though. Are you working with typescript?

Comment: I've just checked, and apparently yes. It'll be a typescript thing. I'll update my question.

Comment: Could you share reproducable example?